# Online code checker,

Tags: performance, security

I'm building a online code checker software.

I'm building a code checker, at times the user may submit code which is harmful for the server or it may even destroy the server, how will you put check on the users code and save your server?

Comment: You didn't ask a question. If you just want an answer to your interview question, that's too broad for Stackoverflow. You can try asking something more specific about it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running linux or unix variants, you can use chroot to run the code in a limited environment.  Also, run processes with appropriate permissions. I would also recommend an outbound iptables firewall so any code can't get out to the internet and potentially download hacker-packs.  The code might still be able to destroy the contents of the chroot, but won't be able to access the system outside.

Bear in mind, Apache in a chroot environment is tricky, especially if you need access to system libs or general functionality.